# I wrote a web api with mvc .net, but I am getting a 404 error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

**my script is bellow**

```
$(function () {
        $(".formSubmit").click(function () {
            var cName = $('#cName').val();
            var cSurname = $('#cSurname').val();
            var cEmail = $('#cEmail').val();
            var cMessage = $('#cMessage').val();
            console.log(cMessage);
            console.log(cEmail);
            console.log(cSurname);
            console.log(cName);
            if (cName != null && cName != '' && cSurname != null && cSurname != '' && cEmail != null && cEmail != '' && cMessage != null && cMessage != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/contactusapi/" + cName + "/" + cSurname + "/" + cEmail + "/" + cMessage + "/?",
                    contentType: "json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != null) {

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**And my "contactusapi" api is below**

```
namespace iskorumacom.Controllers
{
    public class ContactUsApiController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public int Get(string cName, string cSurname, string cEmail, string cMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Data.DataClassesDataContext dc = new Data.DataClassesDataContext())
                {
                string cHTML =
                              "<h3></h3>" +
                              "<b>Ad:</b> " + cName + "<br />" +
                              "<b>Soyad :</b> " + cSurname + "<br />" +
                              "<b>e-Mail :</b> " + cEmail + "<br />" +
                              "<b>Mesaj :</b> " + cMessage;

                using (MailMessage MailMessageLocal = new MailMessage())
                {
                    MailMessageLocal.From =
                        new MailAddress("m@majorworx.com", cName + " " + cSurname, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);


                    MailMessageLocal.To.Add("m@majorworx.com");

                    MailMessageLocal.Subject = "İletişim Formu Formu";
                    MailMessageLocal.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    MailMessageLocal.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    MailMessageLocal.Body = cHTML;
                    MailMessageLocal.Priority = MailPriority.High;

                    using (SmtpClient SmtpClientLocal = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                       
                        return -1;

                    }
                }


            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**and my route.config folder**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "iskorumacom.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: You should not share your code with your login credentials. Be careful.

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't notice

Comment: Your Ajax url has an `api` value. Try to change your `route url` to `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` And you can use a tool (like Postman) to test your api easier.

Comment: "/ api / contactusapi / get /" + cName + "/" + cSurname + "/" + cEmail + "/" + cMessage + "/?" like? Tried but it returns the same error

Comment: Try that: `url: "/api/ContactUsApi/Get?cName=" + cName + "&cSurname=" + cSurname + "&cEmail=" + cEmail + "&cMessage=" + cMessage,`

Comment: I tried but didn't work it.Sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved with @Nikhil Patil

My url is must look like this :

```
url :"/api/contactusapi/" + cName + "/" + cSurname + "/" + cEmail + "/" + cMessage
```

Thanks for your comment and help!

Answer (score 1):

You are controller is inheriting from ApiController, but your route are configured for a MVC controller.

1. If you want to use `ApiController` then configure route using `.MapHttpRoute` method.
2. If you want to configure using `.MapRoute` method then inherit you controller from `Controller` instead of `ApiController`.

Also, in your url you are adding `/api` after your host and port. The `/api` is defined in routeTemplate when defining your route using `.MapHttpRoute` as below -

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In your case configure your WebApiConfig as  -

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And now call your api using url `/api/contactusapi?cName=myname&cSurname=mysurname&cEmail=myemail&cMessage=mymessage`

Or alternatively you can add `Route` attribute to your action method as below -

```
namespace iskorumacom.Controllers
{
   public class ContactUsApiController : ApiController
   {
      [HttpGet]          
      [Route("api/contactus/{cName}/{cSurName}/{cEmail}/{cMessage}")]
      public int Get(string cName, string cSurname, string cEmail, string cMessage) {
         // Your code
      }
   }
}
```

And now call your API as - `/api/contactus/myname/mysurname/myemail/mymessage`

Comment: Thanks i changed my route.config but return error because I have already defined defaultapi in webapi.config

Comment: Can you post both your RouteConfig and WebApiConfig? Also you are using ApiController or Controller?

Comment: I am using api controller

Comment: @Melek, If you using ApiController, then use .MapHttpRoute tin WebApiConfig to configure your routes (use name as 'DefaultApi' here), keep your .MapRoute as it is in RouteConfig (use name as  'Default' here).

Comment: I gues my route and webapi 's code is right cause i used these configurations before and it is work it but now i working local .Do you think the error could be caused by this?

Comment: How does your WebApiConfig look like? If your routeTemplate is "api/{controller}/{id}" then you can call your controller using url = "api/contactusapi/get?cName=" + cName + "&cSurname=" + cSurname + "&cEmail=" + cEmail + "&cMessage=" + cMessage"; Can you also check what is the final url that is getting called in the network tab?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look.

Comment: it returned "System.ArgumentException: The 'DefaultApi' route is already in the routing collection. Redirect names must be unique."

Comment: Check where you have already defined 'DefaultApi' as your route name and change it to something else. If it is for your route.config then change it to 'Default'

Comment: I changed to Default in Route.Config but it is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225967/discussion-between-nikhil-patil-and-melek).

Answer (score 0):

WEBAPİ.CONFİG:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}/{id5}",
                defaults: new {
                    id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    id2 = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    id3 = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    id4 = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    id5 = RouteParameter.Optional
                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: This should work but it is definitely not the y you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Muzaffer Galata comment, you should amend your url to match your end point, see snippet below

```
$(function () {
    $(".formSubmit").click(function () {
        var cName = $('#cName').val();
        var cSurname = $('#cSurname').val();
        var cEmail = $('#cEmail').val();
        var cMessage = $('#cMessage').val();
        console.log(cMessage);
        console.log(cEmail);
        console.log(cSurname);
        console.log(cName);
        //change below
        if (cName != null && cName != '' && cSurname != null && cSurname != '' && cEmail != null && cEmail != '' && cMessage != null && cMessage != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/ContactUsApi/Get?cName=" + cName + "&cSurname=" + cSurname + "&cEmail=" + cEmail + "&cMessage=" + cMessage,
                contentType: "json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {

                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that unfortunately didn't work it